# JW Player VTT thumbnails background messed up by Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, jwplayer, webvtt

I'm using JW Player on a Bootstrap styled site, with tooltip thumnails using a .vtt file. All works well except the JW Player displays a grey background rounded rectangle behind the thumbnails. Bootstrap styles make the gray background behind the thumbnails too narrow, so that the thumbnail stick over the background on the right side. I believe it may have to do with the fact that Bootstrap 3 applies "box-style: border-box" with the universal selector *. If I change the box-sizing to content-box instead of what Bootstrap does (see comments in code below), it fixes the thumbnails background--but of course it messes up the rest of the site. Maybe there is a way to target just the player but I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated.

```
<!-- here is the basic hosted Bootstrap code -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  NOTE if you uncomment this box-sizing immediately below, the problem goes away....
      .... BUT it messes up all of the other Bootstrap styles in the application -->
<!--
<style>
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
</style>
-->

<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/5V3tOP97EeK2SxIxOUCPzg.js"></script>

<div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
    height: 540,
    width: 1280,
    file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/vM7nH0Kl-640.mp4',
    image: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/vM7nH0Kl-640.jpg',
    tracks: [{
      file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/strips/vM7nH0Kl-120.vtt',
      kind: 'thumbnails'
    }]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Comment: I do not have a place for the whole app but this shows the problem in various browsers that I have used: http://testoh.assets.ushmm.org.s3.amazonaws.com/jw-vtt-bootstrap.html Thanks for any help you can provide, Ethan.

Comment: We resolved this over email :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can be fixed by adding the following to your site's :

```
<style>
.jwoverlay {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
</style>
```

Comment: See also http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties for other variants